# mod_rewrite querystring not working locally

Tags: forms, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, get, url-parameters

I need to use mod_rewrite for translate:

`http://example.com/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/?terminos=abcd`

Into:

`http://example.com/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/abcd`

I am using codeigniter framework.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitengoFrontEnd3

# Esto es para el formulario de busqueda
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} terminos=(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1%1? [L]

# Esto para el codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sitengoFrontEnd3.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

In this scenario:

Browsing to:

`http://example.com/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/?terminos=abcd`

Results in (the same):

`http://example.com/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/?terminos=abcd`

I paste LogRewrite Level 9:

```
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] add path info postfix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista -> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/ -> lista/tipo-todo/
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'lista/tipo-todo/'
(4) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] RewriteCond: input='terminos=abcd' pattern='terminos=(.*)'  > matched
(4) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista' pattern='!-f' => matched
(4) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista' pattern='!-d' => matched
(2) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] rewrite 'lista/tipo-todo/' -> 'index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd?'
(3) split uri=index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd? -> uri=index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd, args=<none>
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd -> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(2) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] trying to replace prefix /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/ with /sitengoFrontEnd3
(5) strip matching prefix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd -> index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(4) add subst prefix: index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd -> /sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(1) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] internal redirect with /sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] add path info postfix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php -> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd -> index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd'
(4) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='terminos=(.*)' => not-matched
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] add path info postfix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php -> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd -> index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd'
(4) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] RewriteCond: input='/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd' pattern='^sitengoFrontEnd3.*' => not-matched
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] add path info postfix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php -> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd -> index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd
(3) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/lista/tipo-todo/abcd'
(4) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] RewriteCond: input='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
(1) [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/] pass through /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitengoFrontEnd3/index.php
```

If I change this line of .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1%1? [L]
```

To this other external one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1%1? [L]
```

Then, when I browse to:

`http://example.com/sitengoFrontEnd3/lista/tipo-todo/?terminos=abcd`

Results in:

`http://example2.com/lista/tipo-todo/abcd`

So, why it is working for external&absolute and not for internal & relative?
I have lost a day trying to solve this without success, so any help is welcome.

Comment: In the first two rule sets the incoming URL is mapped to a file (index.php). In the last rewrite rule, it's mapped to a directory as it is in your examples at the top. So, ¿what's exactly what you want, map silently to a file, rewrite to a directory, what? It will help if you give examples of the incoming URL and the mapped URL in each case.

Comment: I would like to get the top ones, the first example. Best regards.

Comment: I would like to get the top ones, the first example. I have a form method=get and i need to receive it in codeigniter URL segments way "(articles/word1+word2" instead of "articles/?search=word1+word2". Best regards.

Comment: You want the address in browser address bar to change from `articles/?search=word1+word2` to `articles/word1%20word2`?

Comment: yes I would like the address to be changed

Comment: I want the plus sign NOT to be encoded, so articles/?search=word1+word2 to articles/word+word2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
Thank you for your comments.
Finally I solved it with the following .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sitengoFrontEnd3


    # Esto es para el formulario de busqueda
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sitengoFrontEnd3.*
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} terminos=(.*)
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]



    # Esto para el codeigniter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sitengoFrontEnd3.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```